# Tabular Input In Create Action

Tags: yii

I have followed this tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table about tabular input but I got stuck.

Everything works fine except filling up inputs. So when someone fill up all fields and I do

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['RacingTable'];
```

It doesn't pick any of my entries and when user doesn't fill everything and it suppose to show error it remove all entries from inputs.

But when I do this

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['RacingTable'][0];
```

It only takes entries from the first group of input fields and then fill up other groups with those entries.

I'm not talking about saving to database. I'm talking about when user do something wrong it takes him back to create action and it should fill that inputs with user's entries.

Answer (score 0):

Post the complete controller/action code so we can get a better picture. For now, I am guessing you are not validating the model properly before trying to save. And tabular input is actually array hence you will not be able to get the value by doing a `$_POST['RacingTable'];` You have to define the index of the array too. That's the reason when you are defining the index [0] in your second line of code it's taking the first set of values. You should run a for loop and try to get all the values defining the index, just like shown in the link you provided.

```
foreach($items as $i=>$item)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['Item'][$i]))
```

If that doesn't solve it, post the complete action code, it's difficult to find out whats wrong just from what you posted.